# Handle a progress dialog in multiple activities

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my project, I need to start a `progress dialog` in one activity and need to stop it in an another activity. Here is my code.

```
progress.setMessage("Searching... ");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.show();
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,BirdsAlgorithm.class );
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

I need to stop this progress bar in `BirdsAlgorithm` class. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. make progress static and public and then in next activity access it through the class name and then stop it.
2. override on destroy and on stop method for activity and then on stop and on destroy stop your progress

Answer (score 1):

The progress dialog **runs on UI thread**. So you should not do anything like this.
Instead you can **dismiss** the progress and **start a new** instance of it in new Activity.